# How to get line-breaks displayed while input in a textarea?

Tags: php, textarea, line-breaks, article, nl2br

After several hours of research, I am still stucked and unable to solve my problem which is this one : get displayed the break line (enter button) input by the user in a textarea.

Indeed, I am trying to code a website with some articles.
These articles are input in a user textarea and saved in a database.
Then I display them in a Home page.
But here is the problem =>

- either I get an output with no break line;
- either I get an output with break line (due to a nl2br function before saving the text in the Db) but in this case I can't click the "Read more" button in the concerned article on the home page.

About this 2nd issue => as the content is noted in the URL link (read.php?title=PHP&content=PHP ...) I am thinking the 
 tag might make the link unworking?

By the way if I right click the Read more button and select open in a new tab, it is working..

Thank you in advance for your help,

Vip4rk

Comment: you can store the text in the DB as it is and echo with nl2br.

Comment: Hey, if I do so I get no line-breaks at all!